# How do I fix Manjaro error hibernation device not found on boot?

Tags: linux, boot, arch-linux, linux-kernel, manjaro

After installing updates and restarting I got these errors.

```
ERROR: resume: hibernation device 'UUID=long number here' not found
ERROR: device '/dev/mapper/ManjaroVG-ManjaroRoot' not found. Skipping fsck.
ERROR: Unable to find root device '/dev/mapper/ManjaroVG-ManjaroRoot'.
```

Then I am dropped to recovery shell with the message `SH: can't access tty: job control turned off`.

This is a less than a week old install I checked lvm and luks encryption on the graphical installer.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this?  I am having a similar issue with Antergos currently.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, how to resolve it?

Answer (score 10):

Did you repartition your swap? If so, the UUID of the swap partition, which is used for hibernation, may have changed. Then this procedure may help.

1. Live-boot and access your filesystem by mounting it.
2. Find the new swap UUID via `sudo blkid`
3. Substitute the old, erroneous UUID with the new UUID in `/etc/fstab/` and `/etc/default/grub`.

Details:

Boot up a live-boot USB. Use `sudo fdisk -l` to find the name of your Linux partition. Then mount it. For example, if your partition is `/dev/sda1` run `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`.

Now `cd /mnt` so you can explore your filesystem. Run `sudo blkid` to find the UUID for your swap partition. If it's not labelled, first use `gparted` to identify which partition is swap.

Comment out the old UUID from `/etc/fstab/` and `/etc/default/grub/` and underneath write a new line of code substituting in the new UUID. Editting the first file will tell your system where the swap directory lives. Editting the second file will suppress the error as it searches for the previous swap UUID.

Answer (score 7):

I keep having this problem in **Arch Linux** and **Manjaro**, when my Laptop runs out of battery while being in *standby*.

My solution in Arch is to run:

```
sudo mkinitcpio -p linux
```

Under **Manjaro** you might have to figure out which kernel to use and then run the command adding the specific kernel-version (pick the higher number if two are available), also you might need to restarts until everything behaves normal again:

```
ls /etc/mkinitcpio.d
sudo mkinitcpio -p linux44 #in my case...
```

Btw, since the system is not booting anymore if you run into this issue, the fallback-boot in Arch/Manjaro usually helps to start the system in the first place. (if someone was wondering ;-) )

It seems `mkinitcpio` resets the boot-process without any side-effects. I would love to here a proper answer and explanation for the issue but for now I am happy to have found a solution.

> mkinitcpio is a Bash script used to create an initial ramdisk environment.

---

**Further readings**:

- [More information about mkinitcpio](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mkinitcpio)
- [Another useful page](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/no-device-specified-for-hibernation/14750/2)

Comment: also this [link](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/no-device-specified-for-hibernation/14750/2)  might help too:

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Feel you free to [edit] your post to add reference, change style etc etc... I added some example of formatting, feel you free to roll back or to improve it.

Comment: Hey Hastur, thanks for the welcome and the formatting :-)

Comment: `sudo mkinitcpio -p linux419` didn't help for me, I still get the same error: `ERROR: resume: hibernation device UUID=8f5d666f-b1bf-48a9-8cce-99bd4842f9f6 not found`. (`ls /etc/mkinitcpio.d` gives `linux414.preset  linux419.preset`).

Answer (score 4):

I am running Manjaro on virtualbox and ran into this issue when I resized my partition. What finally worked for me was:

1. `sudo blkid` to get the new UUID of the swap partition.
2. Replace the UUID in `/etc/fstab` and in `/etc/default/grub`.
3. Generate new `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` with the following command

   ```
   sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
   ```

And reboot. The error message doesn't show up anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Im my case in Manjaro

from here: 
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/error-manjaro-error-hibernation-device-not-found-on-boot/38950/4

In

```
/etc/fstab
```

and

```
/etc/default/grub
```

I removed the lines with
    "UUID=thatnumber_notfound..."

then I used what you say

```
sudo mkinitcpio.conf -p linux419  (in my case of Manjaro with 4.19)
sudo update-grub
```

And that eliminate the error of the device not found

Comment: Dunno so much you can execute `sudo mkinitcpio.conf -p linux419 ` a .conf file :-P

Answer (score 0):

I had this after a dual boot fresh install on Manjaro. Solution was to switch from "RAID On" to "AHCI/NVMe" in the bios.

Does prevent your Windows from booting. But this seems to be [fixable](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Dell_XPS_13_(9300)) and there was no need to mess with any UUID's since they were all correct.

Combination of suggestions [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/new-manjaro-install-dual-boot-gives-cant-find-uuid-error/37909) and [here](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/root-tip-dual-boot-manjaro-and-windows/1164).